# What city does "Twice Upon a Time" take place in?

Tags: film-location, twice-upon-a-time

I've started a French show called "Il Était Une Seconde Fois" or "Twice Upon a Time" in English. I can't tell in which city the action takes place. Any idea?

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Il_%C3%A9tait_une_seconde_fois : Le tournage a débuté le 29 janvier 2018 et s’achève le 6 avril 20186 à Bordeaux7,8, à Paris et à Londres, ainsi qu’en Islande9.